# Double sum to single sum? Simplification.

Tags: summation

Can this double sum be simplified to a single sum and further simplified using geometric series?

$$\left(\sum_{k=1}^{K} s^{2k+1} \left[T^{2k} E e^{(r)}\right]_\beta \right)
\left(\sum_{m=1}^{M} s^{2m} \left[T_2^{2m-1} E_2 e^{(r)}\right]_\beta \right)$$

Thanks!!

Comment: Probably not. And definitely not until the meaning of symbols is understood. For example, what does the subscript $\beta$ do to the square brackers?

Comment: Pleas use LaTeX markup, and explain the symbols used.

Comment: is "T" triangular function ?  or "S" and "T" 's orthogonal ?

Comment: Sorry guys; T=nxn matrix, E=nxm matrix, e(r)=vector of 1's length n, beta=chooses beta'th elemtn of this triple matrix multiplication.

Comment: What is $T$ vs. $T_2$? $E$ vs. $E_2$?